# Simplify ${\rm trace}((A_1⊗A_2+B_1⊗B_2)^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, svd, kronecker-product

This equation is take a long time in simulation due to [Kronecker product](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Kronecker-product-properties) ($⊗$).

> Simplify $${\rm tr}((A_1⊗A_2+B_1⊗B_2)^{-1})$$
> where **tr** is trace operator (sum of diagonal elements).
> Also, $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ are orthonormal matrix. 
> Is there a way to simplify (make it without $⊗$) ?

---

**We have these properties:**

- $\mathrm{tr}(A \otimes B) = \mathrm{tr}(A)\mathrm{tr}(B)$
- $\mathrm{tr}(A+B) = \mathrm{tr}(A) + \mathrm{tr}(B)$
- $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$
- $(A \otimes B)^{-1} = (A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1})$
- $||A||^2 = \mathrm{tr}(A^{\dagger}A)$
- $\mathrm{tr}(A^{\dagger}A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\min(m,n)}\sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma$ is the singular value of $A$
- $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$
- $\mathrm{tr}(A^{-1}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\lambda_i}$
- $\mathrm{tr}\left((I+A)^{-1}\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\lambda_i+1}$, where $I$ is the identity matrix
- $\mathrm{tr}\left((I+A \otimes B)^{-1}\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\min(m,n)}\dfrac{1}{\lambda_i^{AB} +1}$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, $\lambda^{AB}=\lambda^A \otimes \lambda^B$ and $\lambda^A$,$\lambda^B$ are eigenvalue vectors for A, B respectively
- $(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = AC \otimes BD$

---

This equation is used to calculate the performance of telecommunication system with Intelligent Reflector Surface (IRS)

The simplification will reduce the computational complexity.

Comment: Could you give some context regarding this problem? Why are you interested in it?

Comment: Do you have any specific information about $A$ and $B$? For example, are any of the matrices $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ necessarily symmetric? Are any necessarily positive definite? Are the matrices $B_1,B_2$ "small" (in norm) relative to $A_1,A_2$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I updated the question.

Comment: @AIASAD I’m not sure what an “orthonormal matrix” is. Are these square matrices? If not, is it the rows that are orthonormal or the columns?

Comment: @BenGrossmann "orthonormal" is a pretty common term, because just saying "orthogonal" can be confusing: two vectors are orthogonal if $⟨u∣v⟩=0$, so one would expect an orthogonal matrix to simply be a (square) matrix so that distinct rows/columns are pairwise orthogonal. However, this condition only gives $U^⊤U=D$, and in practice we often want $U^⊤U=$. Hence, "orthonormal" = "orthogonal" + "normalized". I'm surprised you haven't heard it before.

Comment: @Hyperplane That was what I figured when I put my answer together. I suppose that in the context with which I am familiar, people cling to the older but confusing terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you say that $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ are "orthonormal", you mean that they are square, [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) matrices. I also assume that $A_1,B_1$ have the same shape, and $A_2,B_2$ have the same shape. I also assume that $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ happen to be such that $A_1 \otimes A_2 + B_1 \otimes B_2$ is invertible.

If that is the case, then instead of directly computing the inverse of one large matrix, we can use the diagaonlization of two small matrices. Note that we can rewrite
$$
(A_1 \otimes A_2 + B_1 \otimes B_2)^{-1} = (I + (A_1^TB_1) \otimes (A_2^TB_2))^{-1}(A_1 \otimes A_2)^T.
$$
From there, we can use the [spectral theorem for normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) to write $$
A_j^TB_j = U_jD_jU_j^*, \quad j = 1,2
$$
where each $U_j$ is a (typically complex) unitary matrix, $D_j$ is a (typically complex) diagonal matrix (whose diagonal entries have magnitude $1$), and $U^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $U$. Here, we are using the fact that $A_j^TB_j$ is orthogonal, therefore normal, therefore unitarily diagonalizable.

We then compute
$$
(I + (A_1^TB_1) \otimes (A_2^TB_2))^{-1} = \\
(I + (U_1D_1U_1^*) \otimes (U_2D_2U_2^*))^{-1} = \\
([U_1 \otimes U_2][I + D_1 \otimes D_2][U_1 \otimes U_2]^*)^{-1} = \\
(U_1 \otimes U_2)(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}(U_1 \otimes U_2)^*.
$$
Because $I + D_1 \otimes D_2$ is diagonal, its inverse is easily computed. Putting everything together, we have
$$
(A_1 \otimes A_2 + B_1 \otimes B_2)^{-1} = (U_1 \otimes U_2)(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}(U_1 \otimes U_2)^*(A_1 \otimes A_2)^T, 
$$
and from here we can compute the trace.

Alternatively, if there is a nice way to express $(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}$ in the form
$$
(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1} = \sum_{k=1}^p P_k \otimes Q_k
$$
with $P_k,Q_k$ having the same shape as $A_1,A_2$ respectively, then we can truly remove any Kronecker products from the computation.

---

Decomposing $(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}$: Let $m,n$ denote the sizes of $A_1,A_2$ respectively. We note that $(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}$ is diagonal with
$$
[(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}]_{n(j-1) + k, n(j-1)+k} = \frac{1}{1 + [D_1]_{jj}[D_2]_{kk}}.
$$
Let $E_{j,k}$ denote the $m \times m$ matrix whose $j,k$ entry is $1$ and whose other entries are zero. Let $M_j$ denote the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are equal to $\frac{1}{1 + [D_1]_{jj}[D_2]_{kk}}$ for $k = 1,\dots,n$. We find that
$$
(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1} = \sum_{j=1}^m E_{jj} \otimes M_j.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
(A_1 \otimes A_2 + B_1 \otimes B_2)^{-1} &= (U_1 \otimes U_2)(I + D_1 \otimes D_2)^{-1}(U_1 \otimes U_2)^*(A_1 \otimes A_2)^T
\\ & = 
(U_1 \otimes U_2)\left(\sum_{j=1}^m E_{jj} \otimes M_j\right)(U_1 \otimes U_2)^*(A_1 \otimes A_2)^T
\\ & = \sum_{j=1}^n (U_1 E_{jj}U_1^* A_1^T) \otimes (U_2 M_j U_2^* A_2^T),
\end{align}
So that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[(A_1 \otimes A_2 + B_1 \otimes B_2)^{-1}] &=
\operatorname{Tr}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n (U_1 E_{jj}U_1^* A_1^T) \otimes (U_2 M_j U_2^* A_2^T) \right]
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Tr}(U_1 E_{jj}U_1^* A_1^T) \operatorname{Tr} (U_2 M_j U_2^* A_2^T).
\end{align}
Moreover, the first trace in the product can be simplified dramatically:
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(U_1 E_{jj}U_1^* A_1^T) = 
\operatorname{Tr}(E_{jj}U_1^* A_1^TU_1) = [U_1^*A_1^TU_1]_{jj}.
$$
The computation of the second trace in the product can be made more efficient by rewriting
$$
\operatorname{Tr} (U_2 M_j U_2^* A_2^T) = 
\operatorname{Tr} (M_j [U_2^* A_2^TU_2]),
$$
so that the product $U_2^* A_2^TU_2$ can be computed once and reused for the successive computations of $\operatorname{Tr} (M_j [U_2^* A_2^TU_2])$.

Comment: Thanks very much
this is matlab code
%% this function to calculate trace(inv(kron(A1,A2)+kron(B1,B2)))
function r=trace_kron(A1,A2,B1,B2)
X1=A1\B1;
X2=A2\B2;
[Ux1 Ex1]=eig(X1);
[Ux2 Ex2]=eig(X2);
ex1=diag(Ex1);
ex2=diag(Ex2);
r=0;
temp = (A1*Ux1)\Ux1;
temp1=(A2*Ux2)\Ux2;
for k = 1:length(ex1)
r=r+temp(k,k)*trace(1./(ex1(k)*ex2+1).*eye(length(ex2))*temp1);
end
It will also work with non orthonormal matrix